# md-list-icon or md-button aligned to right? (Angular Material 2)

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Any way how to make buttons/icons/checkboxes aligned to the right like in Material 1:

[image: Angular Material 1 list with actions]
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/list

I currently (Material 2) have:

```
<md-list>
  <md-list-item *ngFor="let position of cart">
    <h3 md-line> {{ position.name }} </h3>
    <p md-line>
      <span> Line 1 </span>
    </p>
    <md-icon md-list-icon>delete</md-icon>
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

[image: Angular Material 2 list with actions]

Comment: Umm, doesn't Angular still use CSS for customization? That would mean this is a simple `float: right;`

Comment: float:right is not working... After playing with it for a while I came up with a solution, I'll post it in a moment

Comment: 'float: right' work for me.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

For what is described above the solution is pretty simple, simply omit `mat-list-icon` in your selector and Material will do the magic:

```
<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let position of cart">
    <h3 mat-line> {{ position.name }} </h3>
    <p mat-line>
      <span> Line 1 </span>
    </p>
    <div> $2.00 </div>
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="remove(1)">
      <mat-icon class="mat-24">delete</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

[image]

Comment: you meant to omit `md-list-icon`!? ;)

Comment: @srokatonie mind to accept the answer? I had to scan all the other answers just in case.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, mat-list uses flex box. You can individually order the item using the CSS property 'order'. Just use a large enough number for the order

```css
md-icon[md-list-icon]{
  order: 10;
}
```

```html
<md-list>
  <md-list-item *ngFor="let position of cart">
    <h3 md-line> {{ position.name }} </h3>
    <p md-line>
      <span> Line 1 </span>
    </p>
    <md-icon md-list-icon>delete</md-icon>
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

Comment: This is the best solution since it doesn't make use of the <button> element

Answer (score 7):

For those of you wondering in 2023: Angular 15 comes with a specific directive for this, `MatListItemMeta`.

**Example**

```html
<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let position of cart">
    <h3 matListItemTitle> {{ position.name }} </h3>
    <p matListItemLine>Line 1</p>
    <button matListItemMeta mat-icon-button (click)="remove(1)">
      <mat-icon class="mat-24">delete</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Comment: This works. Need to make sure you preventDefault though if using a selection list

Answer (score 1):

If anyone like me had this same problem and the suggested solutions didn't work out try this:

```css
.icon-class {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<mat-list>
   <mat-list-item>
      {{"Im just a filler"}}
      <mat-icon class="icon-class">
          fiber_manual_record
      </mat-icon>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    </mat-list-item>
<mat-list>
```

It worked for me, and when it did I got mad at myself for not figuring it out before

Answer (score -6):

You can also achieve this with **dir** attribute

```html
<md-list dir="rtl">
  ...
</md-list>
```

Comment: That's a terrible solution.  Note that if you're using multiple icons (like in the example image shown) the icons will end up in reverse order.  Also, screen readers will likely read out the controls in the wrong order.  Don't do this.  `dir="rtl"` is designed for cases when the content will be interpreted as the item on the right being logically first, not for visually rearranging things.

Comment: I agree with Jules. This is not the right solution for this kind of problem.